# Analytic properties of a function such that $f(x)-f(y)=f(x/y)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisifies $f(x)-f(y)=f(x/y)$ for all $x,y\in (0,\infty)$ and $f(1)=0$.

What I need to do is prove that $f$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ if and only if $f$ is continuous at 1. One direction is trivial. What I'm having trouble with showing that if $f$ is continuous at 1 then $f$ is continuous on the entire interval.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $f$ is continuous at $1$.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Pick $\delta > 0$ such that $|t-1| < \delta \implies |f(t)| < \varepsilon$.

Fix $y_0 \in (0,\infty)$ and set $\delta' := \delta|y_0| > 0$.

Then for $x > 0$ such that $|x-y_0| < \delta'$ we have $\left|\frac{x}{y_0} -1\right| < \frac{\delta'}{y_0} = \delta$ so $$\left|f(x) - f(y_0)\right| = \left|f\left(\frac{x}{y_0}\right)\right| < \varepsilon$$

We conclude that $f$ is continuous at $y_0$.

Comment: Your answer is somewhat unclear. In particular how are you guaranteed that $|x-y_0|<\delta|y_0|$?

Comment: in essence, he is defining $\delta ' = \delta'(\epsilon,y_0) = \delta(1,\epsilon)\cdot |y_0|$. Thus, given $\epsilon, y_0$, you may use the provided $\delta'$

Comment: @Walt For given $\varepsilon > 0$ I defined $\delta' = \delta|y_0| > 0$ and showed that for every $x > 0$ we have $|x-y_0| < \delta' \implies |f(x) - f(y_0)| < \varepsilon$. Hence $f$ is continuous at $y_0$ by definition.

Answer (score 1):

$f(xt) = f(x) + f(t)$.  Think of this as a function of $t$.  The right side is continuous at $t=1$ if and only if $f$ is continuous at $1$.  The left side is continuous at $t=1$ if and only if $f$ is continuous at $x$.